ATX Standard: What terminals to use for custom crimped cables?
I want to shorten my PC cables (e.g. the 24-pin mainboard and CPU cable), so I need to put on new terminals on the wires.
I am unsure if the specification for ATX12V 2.53, ATX 3.0 and ATX 3.1 is even available to the public, but what so far is clear, that Molex Mini-Fit is the product series that is used for ATX PSUs. However, Mini-Fit is not Mini-Fit, in fact there are a ton of different terminals available, e.g. some made of phosphor bronze or gold plated ones.
Also, I found the names

Mini-Fit Jr.
Mini-Fit Sr.
Mini-Fit HCS
Mini-Fit Plus
Mini-Fit Plus HCS

whereas I am not sure if Plus, HCS and Plus HCS is actually the same. HCS seems to stand for High-Current System. Mini-Fit Sr. on the other hand seems to be incompatible to Mini-Fit Jr, as the terminals look much different.
Questions

Does someone know what exactly type (Jr., HCS/Plus/Plus HCS) can be
used and if my assumption, that only the tinned ones may be used,
while the gold plated ones must not be used?
With ATX 3.0 and 3.1, we now also have 12VHPWR which was replaced by
12V-2x6. Is this Micro-Fit and if yes, what type of it, including
the type of plating? It seems there is at least a "Micro-Fit+".



The typical ATX connectors for 20/24-pin Power, 4/8-pin EPS 12V, 6-pin PCIe, and 8-pin PCIe are all part of the Mini-Fit Jr. series.
See answers to this question for the housing part numbers.
The crimp terminals for all of these are the 5556 series. There are many different options to choose from. Pick one that matches the wire size of your cables (e.g. 16AWG and 18AWG are commonly used sizes).
I don't see why you couldn't use the gold plated contacts, but not can I see any reason why you should. They main reason they aren't commonly used is probably just that they cost more. There is no real benefit because the connectors tend to be plugged in once and forgotten about.
All the PSUs I've come across in my time have used tin plated crimps.

Yes the new 12-pin PCIe connectors are Micro-Fit connectors, specifically the 43025 series - e.g. 43025-1208.
The crimp terminals for those are the 43030 series. Again, pick one that suits your wire diameter.



Wouldn't the combination of gold plated and tinned contacts lead to galvanic corrosion?

@Tintenfisch More likely to get fretting corrosion, but given it's not a high vibration environment and only a single insertion, it is unlikely to be a big problem. Given everyone else seems to use Tin plated contacts, I'd stick with them too. You won't get galvanic corrosion because the tin tends to dissolve the gold.

Alright. First, thanks a lot for your answer! But there is something interesting, and it is this sheet from Molex ("MINI-FIT® PCI EXPRESS®"). From what I can see, they in fact list both "Mini-Fit" (is that Jr.?) and "Mini-Fit Plus" for the terminals. Probably Mini-Fit (Jr?) is used for the large 24-pin ATX and for PCIe (= CPU, GPU) Mini-Fit Plus is used?

@Tintenfisch Plus is just a higher current (13A/pin) version of Jr (9A/pin). None of the ATX connectors require that level of current. EPS12V (the 8-pin one) is 336W, which works out as 7A/pin (336W/12V/4pin). The 8-pin PCIe connector is max 150W, or 6.25A/pin (150W/12V/2pin). No need for the high current versions - it would do no harm using them, but they aren't really necessary.

Correction for above - PCIe 8-pin has 3x 12V and 3x GND connections, so actually max 4.2A/pin.

Thanks a lot! Ended with ordering a bunch of 39000077 terminals (I use 17 AWG, but should work with the right tool).
